# apt-get update Bad header line on all updates

Tags: apt, updates, proxy

I am behind a proxy so I have updated `/etc/apt/apt.conf` with my proxy settings and I have removed the old lists with `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`.

However I still get the following when I run `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed InRelease
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed Release.gpg
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed Release
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/main amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/universe amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/restricted i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/main i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/universe i386 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en_GB
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/main Translation-en_GB
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/main Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/multiverse Translation-en_GB
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/restricted Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/restricted Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/universe Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/universe Translation-en
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en_GB
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_GB
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en_GB
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en_GB
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
  Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en_GB
  Bad header line
Err http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
  Bad header line
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/Release.gpg  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release.gpg  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/source/Sources  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/source/Sources  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/source/Sources  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/source/Sources  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/main/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/source/Sources  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/source/Sources  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/main/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/main/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-proposed/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Got a single header line over 360 chars

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB  Bad header line

W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Bad header line
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. This is an Ethernet connection in the office which goes to a Sophos proxy.

Comment: Try going to http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-i386/ and downloading files with your browser (just to check if it works), proxy might be blocking your updates.

Comment: works fine in firefox.. trying to see if there is other proxy setting for the terminal that it's looking for?

Comment: Ah.. just found the following at the bottom of the following post: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-desktop-to-use-your-proxy-server.html 
First you need to edit /etc/bash.bashrc file

    gksudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc

Add your proxy server details in the following format

    export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
    export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
However now I get 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: Still get this issue.. Additionally I also get Bad header issue in Synaptic with my proxy settings added

Comment: What does it happens if you connect to one of these addresses? For example: curl -I http://...

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>407 Proxy Authentication Required</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Authentication Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>

Comment: I'm seeing this on Rackspace servers over IPv6 with lines like:
`Got a single header line over 360 chars [IP: ::ffff:67.215.65.132 80]`.  No solution found yet...

Comment: Seems my problem was due to OpenDNS causing a redirect loop.  See [my answer below](http://askubuntu.com/a/453219/19264) for the fix.

Answer (score 12):

I hit this issue with one of the `ppa`s (`Geogebra`), a few minutes back and doing the following solved the issue:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up apt-get correctly to be able to use it behind a proxy:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's down. I like to use http://www.isup.me/ to verify if a site is down or not.

Comment: it's an internal Proxy.. It's up or I wouldn't be able to write this to you now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using OpenDNS, but if you are that could be the problem.  Today (04/22/2014) there appears to be a problem with the [OpenDNS search page](http://guide.opendns.com/).

I was getting various network errors with `sudo apt-get update` such as:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
  Got a single header line over 360 chars [IP: ::ffff:67.215.65.132 80]
```

I was also seeing 303 Redirect Loops with miscellaneous URLs like:

```
$ wget -d http://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.13.4 on linux-gnu.

URI encoding = `UTF-8'
--2014-04-22 22:29:34--  http://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key
Resolving debian.datastax.com (debian.datastax.com)... ::ffff:67.215.65.132, 173.203.57.192
Caching debian.datastax.com => ::ffff:67.215.65.132 173.203.57.192
Connecting to debian.datastax.com (debian.datastax.com)|::ffff:67.215.65.132|:80... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000000fffad0 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /debian/repo_key HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: debian.datastax.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.0 303 See Other
Location: http://guidetest.a.id.opendns.com/?url=debian%2Edatastax%2Ecom%2Fdebian%2Frepo%5Fkey
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 22 Apr 2014 22:29:34 GMT
Server: OpenDNS Guide

---response end---
303 See Other
Location: http://guidetest.a.id.opendns.com/?url=debian%2Edatastax%2Ecom%2Fdebian%2Frepo%5Fkey [following]
Closed fd 3
URI content encoding = None
--2014-04-22 22:29:34--  http://guidetest.a.id.opendns.com/?url=debian%2Edatastax%2Ecom%2Fdebian%2Frepo%5Fkey
Resolving guidetest.a.id.opendns.com (guidetest.a.id.opendns.com)... ::ffff:67.215.65.132, 67.215.67.10
Caching guidetest.a.id.opendns.com => ::ffff:67.215.65.132 67.215.67.10
Connecting to guidetest.a.id.opendns.com (guidetest.a.id.opendns.com)|::ffff:67.215.65.132|:80... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000000ffdd40 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /?url=debian%2Edatastax%2Ecom%2Fdebian%2Frepo%5Fkey HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: guidetest.a.id.opendns.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.0 303 See Other
Location: http://guidetest.a.id.opendns.com/?url=guidetest%2Ea%2Eid%2Eopendns%2Ecom%2F%3Furl%3Ddebian%252Edatastax%252Ecom%252Fdebian%252Frepo%255Fkey
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 22 Apr 2014 22:29:34 GMT
Server: OpenDNS Guide

---response end---

[...SNIP MANY 303 REDIRECTS...]


303 See Other
Location: http://guidetest.a.id.opendns.com/?url=guidetest%2Ea%2Eid%2Eopendns%2Ecom%2F%3Furl%3Dguidetest%252Ea%252Eid%252Eopendns%252Ecom%252F%253Furl%253Dguidetest%25252Ea%25252Eid%25252Eopendns%25252Ecom%25252F%25253Furl%25253Dguidetest%2525252Ea%2525252Eid%2525252Eopendns%2525252Ecom%2525252F%2525253Furl%2525253Dguidetest%252525252Ea%252525252Eid%252525252Eopendns%252525252Ecom%252525252F%252525253Furl%252525253Dguidetest%25252525252Ea%25252525252Eid%25252525252Eopendns%25252525252Ecom%25252525252F%25252525253Furl%25252525253Dguidetest%2525252525252Ea%2525252525252Eid%2525252525252Eopendns%2525252525252Ecom%2525252525252F%2525252525253Furl%2525252525253Dguidetest%252525252525252Ea%252525252525252Eid%252525252525252Eopendns%252525252525252Ecom%252525252525252F%252525252525253Furl%252525252525253Dguidetest%25252525252525252Ea%25252525252525252Eid%25252525252525252Eopendns%25252525252525252Ecom%25252525252525252F%25252525252525253Furl%25252525252525253Dguidetest%2525252525252525252Ea%2525252525252525252Eid%2525252525252525252Eopendns%2525252525252525252Ecom%2525252525252525252F%2525252525252525253Furl%2525252525252525253Dguidetest%252525252525252525252Ea%252525252525252525252Eid%252525252525252525252Eopendns%252525252525252525252Ecom%252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525253Furl%252525252525252525253Dguidetest%25252525252525252525252Ea%25252525252525252525252Eid%25252525252525252525252Eopendns%25252525252525252525252Ecom%25252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525253Furl%25252525252525252525253Dguidetest%2525252525252525252525252Ea%2525252525252525252525252Eid%2525252525252525252525252Eopendns%2525252525252525252525252Ecom%2525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525253Furl%2525252525252525252525253Dguidetest%252525252525252525252525252Ea%252525252525252525252525252Eid%252525252525252525252525252Eopendns%252525252525252525252525252Ecom%252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525253Furl%252525252525252525252525253Dguidetest%25252525252525252525252525252Ea%25252525252525252525252525252Eid%25252525252525252525252525252Eopendns%25252525252525252525252525252Ecom%25252525252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252525253Furl%25252525252525252525252525253Dguidetest%2525252525252525252525252525252Ea%2525252525252525252525252525252Eid%2525252525252525252525252525252Eopendns%2525252525252525252525252525252Ecom%2525252525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252525253Furl%2525252525252525252525252525253Dguidetest%252525252525252525252525252525252Ea%252525252525252525252525252525252Eid%252525252525252525252525252525252Eopendns%252525252525252525252525252525252Ecom%252525252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525252525253Furl%252525252525252525252525252525253Dguidetest%25252525252525252525252525252525252Ea%25252525252525252525252525252525252Eid%25252525252525252525252525252525252Eopendns%25252525252525252525252525252525252Ecom%25252525252525252525252525252525252F%25252525252525252525252525252525253Furl%25252525252525252525252525252525253Dguidetest%2525252525252525252525252525252525252Ea%2525252525252525252525252525252525252Eid%2525252525252525252525252525252525252Eopendns%2525252525252525252525252525252525252Ecom%2525252525252525252525252525252525252F%2525252525252525252525252525252525253Furl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253Dguidetest%252525252525252525252525252525252525252Ea%252525252525252525252525252525252525252Eid%252525252525252525252525252525252525252Eopendns%252525252525252525252525252525252525252Ecom%252525252525252525252525252525252525252F%252525252525252525252525252525252525253Furl%252525252525252525252525252525252525253Ddebian%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252Edatastax%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252Ecom%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252Fdebian%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252Frepo%25252525252525252525252525252525252525255Fkey [following]
Closed fd 3
URI content encoding = None
20 redirections exceeded.
```

To fix this, I switched `/etc/resolv.conf` to use GoogleDNS:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

It was previously using OpenDNS (e.g. `nameserver 208.67.222.222` & `nameserver 208.67.220.220`)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing the server to old-releases.ubuntu.com instead of cc.archives.ubuntu.com, you need to change the protocol from simple http to encrypted https. Worked for me!

BTW, you can use "sed" to automatically do both replacements.